# How to use the T-test

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

Suppose a scenario where we have 5 `Evolutionary Algorithms` whose objective is to reach the global minimum for a function `f(x)` which is 0. Closer the algorithm to the global minimum the better.

All the algorithms are run for 25 times independently and their data is recorded  as follows

```
algorithm 1: val1, val2, ..., val25  |  mean 1 = 15
algorithm 2: val1, val2, ..., val25  |  mean 2 = 0.5
algorithm 3: val1, val2, ..., val25  |  mean 3 = 0.6
algorithm 4: val1, val2, ..., val25  |  mean 4 = 5
algorithm 5: val1, val2, ..., val25  |  mean 5 = 10
```

We can easily rank `algorithm 1`, `algorithm 4` and `algorithm 5` as the gap in the mean is more. But as mean of `algorithm 2` and `algorithm 3` are very close we can not conclude that `algorithm 2` is better just because it's mean is smaller than mean of `algorithm 3`. So we decided to perform a `T-test` (Independent-Samples T-Test) on `algorithm 2` and `algorithm 3` data to find whether there is any significant difference in their mean. Results reveal that there is a significant difference in their mean, So we concluded that `algorithm 2` is better than `algorithm 3`.

My question is

- have used T-test correctly
- does more statistical analysis is required to compare the algorithm or above approach is suffice

Any comments would be of great help, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think typically, you would first run a oneway ANOVA comparing all algorithms. If the overall F-test is significant for the ANOVA, this means there are at least two algorithms that differ from each other. From here, you can do post-hoc tests, which test the difference between pairs of groups. Significant results of post-hoc tests indicate true differences between the algorithms.

The problem with your approach is that you have implicitly run many hypothesis tests. You implicitly tested whether all algorithms had the same score (a hypothesis which you rejected), and then implicitly tested whether all pairs of algorithms were different. Although it may be clear that you are not falsely claiming 1 and 4 are different from each other, the fact is that you have implicitly made a lot of statistical claims about the ordering of the mean scores for the algorithms. This amounts to performing multiple comparisons, which statisticians have developed tests for. The post-hoc tests I mentioned previously account for multiple comparisons. This prevents the user from falsely claiming two groups are different when they are not, the probability of which increases when many tests are run.

That said, your specific goals may not be to protect yourself from false alarms but rather to test whether the magnitude of the difference between the scores of the algorithms is large enough, in which case a t-test is probably fine (although it would benefit from being within the ANOVA framework to better estimate the mean squared error between groups).